# encodings - different result between codePointCount and length

Tags: java, encoding

I found one tricky place and couldn't find any answer why this exactly happen.

The main problem is how long is string.

Whether it contains one or two character.

**Code:**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char ch0 = 55378;
        char ch1 = 56816;
        String str = new String(new char[]{ch0, ch1});
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(str.length());
        System.out.println(str.codePointCount(0, 2));
        System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(str.charAt(1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
?
2
1
?
?
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to take some time out going through [this article](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whether it contains one or two character.

It contains one Unicode *character*, which is comprised of 2 UTF-16 *code units*. Every `char` in Java is a UTF-16 code unit... it may not be a whole character. Each character has a single code point - Unicode provides a *coded character set* mapping each character to an integer representing that character (the code point).

`length()` returns the number of code units, whereas `codePointCount` returns the number of code points.

You may want to look at my article about [encodings in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx) - the terminology all translates fine (as it's standard terminology), so just ignore the .NET-specific parts.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for